# While(true) loop halting?

Tags: c#, multithreading, while-loop, infinite-loop

Currently learning to use Threads, and made a console application that writes random ASCII characters to the console window. The method I created works just fine, but the text halts after about three and half(ish) lines through. Why might the loop stop? Not that I need the loop to run forever or anything, I am just curious as to why a (what should be) infinite loop halts unexpectedly. Here is the code I am working with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 Thread ThreadKeyboard = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RandomKeyboard));
 ThreadKeyboard.Start();
        //Wait for input
        Console.Read();
 ThreadKeyboard.Abort();
}

public static void RandomKeyboard()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Random Keyboard Thread Started");

    while (true)
    {
        char key = (char)(rand.Next(25)+65);
        if (rand.Next(2) == 0)
        {
            key = char.ToLower(key);
        }

        SendKeys.SendWait(key.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(50));
    }     
}
```

Comment: replace `SendKeys.SendWait(key.ToString());` with `Console.WriteLine(key.ToString())`

Comment: `SendWait`: "Sends the given keys to the active application, and then waits for the messages to be processed." - Is this where it's halting?

Comment: if in doubt read the manual, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TheGeneral So would that mean that the SendWait() method can only hold a string so large?

Comment: @Zach "can only hold a string so large" - Where are you getting that idea? In your code you are sending a single key.

Comment: @john well I assumed it could only hold a string that was equally as long as the three lines or so it had typed into the console and then started waiting for the response from the "application" which in this case, can't respond anyway.

Comment: @john I;m sending one key at a time, sleeping, and sending another. If it was waiting for the response, it would've only sent one key to begin with, wouldn't you think?

Comment: Why would it only have sent one? The receiving application likely stopped handling the key presses at some point. Test your code with notepad or something.

Comment: Wait. I just re-read your question. To clarify, are you trying to write to the console of the same application, or to another application's input? What you're doing at the moment is simulating user input.

Comment: it would write to any application's input, if I needed it inside the console, I would simply use `Console.Write(key.ToString())`

Comment: I've tested your code and if I tab to notepad after the input stops appearing, I see that it continues writing into notepad, so it seems that the console application stops handling the input and `SendWait` just hangs. Why that is, I'm not sure.